# cannot read/ get file when try to upload using java struts action

Tags: java, file-upload, struts

i'm trying to upload excel file below my code:

im using bootstrap, blueimp plugin and struts action.

this is the request:
------WebKitFormBoundary5peQFGFm3lEKCOB5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

SMSMassploadOladDate.xls

------WebKitFormBoundary5peQFGFm3lEKCOB5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileInput"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

------WebKitFormBoundary5peQFGFm3lEKCOB5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sub"

------WebKitFormBoundary5peQFGFm3lEKCOB5--

the file is being set null in java action
i was trying to get file using httpServletReques:

```
public String uploadMassContentsFromExcelSheetNew() {
    HSSFSheet sheet = null;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    result=new JSONObject();

    try {
            if (fileName != null){
            fileName=fileName.trim();

        if  (fileName.endsWith(".xls") || fileName.endsWith(".xlsx") )  {
            String  filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext();
            HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            System.out.println("Parts*******:"+request.getParts()); //return null

            Part filePart =request.getPart("fileInput");//return null
            MultiPartRequestWrapper multiWrapper=(MultiPartRequestWrapper)ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            File[] f=multiWrapper.getFiles("fileInput"); //return null
            String fileName=multiWrapper.getFileNames("fileInput")[0];
            Enumeration fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getParameterNames();
            String param = request.getParameter("fileInput");
        }
            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

jsp code:

```
<html>
<form name="massUploadForm" id="fileupload" action="uploadMassContentsFromExcelSheetNew.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="doMassValidate();">           
                                          <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" value=""/>
                                             <div id='fileDiv' class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                            <span>addFile</span>
                                            <input type="file"  name="fileInput" id="fileInput"  accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
                                            </span>

                                            </div>

                                                </div>  

                                            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
                                                <tbody class="files" id="addedFilesBody"></tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <button  name="sub" type="submit" ></button>
                                                        </form>
<html>
```

Comment: Check whether the session is actually created or not. servletRequest.getSession() print this value and post.

Comment: the session is created and its value "org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3e27b866", the hidden field is set with the right value except the file is null.

Comment: What is the value of request?

Comment: value of request: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequestWrapper@53c58cb0

Comment: The values are not set at header lever may be. Can you check the headers are properly formed at request generator?

Comment: i have read request header these are the values: 
connection value:keep-alive
content-length value:914
cache-control value:max-age=0
origin value:http://localhost:8080
upgrade-insecure-requests value:1
user-agent value:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
content-type value:multipart/form-data;
boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrrz7HqtvMtkeKLA5
accept value: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding value:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language value:en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: i want to ask when i get request param i just get the hidden field, is file missing or should not be one of the param?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to upload file, but not being sent by the request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627118/trying-to-upload-file-but-not-being-sent-by-the-request)

Comment: sorry this question i was trying to upload file using blueimp plugin, the other question i have used bootstrap and struts plugin to upload.

Comment: @Rasha bluimp plugin doesn't exist for struts, and there's no integration available.

Comment: @RomanC i guess also that blueimp doesn't support upload file of type excel