# trying to upload file, but not being sent by the request

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to upload file using input of type file, also I have another param I want to submit

below my form code:

```xml
<form  id="fileupload" action="uploadMassContentsFromExcelSheetNew"  method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return doMassValidate();"  >          

      <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" value=""/>
      <input type="hidden" id="serviceIdMass" name="serviceIdMass"   value=""/>
      <input type="hidden" id="contentTypeMass" name="contentTypeMass"   value=""/> 



     <div id='fileDiv' class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group-file">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        disabled="disabled" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
             <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
        <i class="icon md-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input type="file" name="files" id="uploadBtn">
          </span>
          </span>   
        <p style="word-wrap: break-word;">
            <small id="fileError" style="display: none;"
                            class="help-block" data-fv-validator="notEmpty"
                            data-fv-result="VALIDATED">
                <s:property value="getText('content.file.error')" />
            </small>
        </p>

        </div>
        </div>
     </div> 

            <button  name="sub" type="submit" >submit</button>

</form>
```

JS code:

```js
function doMassValidate(){
    var hasSelectedFile=checkIfHasSelectedFile();
    if(!hasSelectedFile){
        fileErrorMessage();
        $("#fileError").hide();

        return false;
    }
    else{
        removeErrorClass('fileDiv');
        return true;
    }
}
function checkIfHasSelectedFile(){
    var hasNotUploadFile=   $('#uploadBtn').val(); 
    if(hasNotUploadFile=="" || hasNotUploadFile=='' )
         return false;
     else return true;

}
```

this is my action:

```java
public String uploadMassContentsFromExcelSheetNew() {
    HSSFSheet sheet = null;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    result=new JSONObject();

    try {
            if (fileName != null){
            fileName=fileName.trim();

        if  (fileName.endsWith(".xls") || fileName.endsWith(".xlsx") )  {

    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
                System.out.println("Parts*******:"+request.getParts()); //return   null


                MultiPartRequestWrapper multiWrapper=(MultiPartRequestWrapper)ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            String fileNameParam=servletRequest.getParameter("fileName");//i get the file name value
String fileParam=servletRequest.getParameter("files");// i cant get param with name "files" when i inspect the servletRequest

            Part filePart =request.getPart("files");//return null
            File[] f=multiWrapper.getFiles("files"); //return null
            String fileName=multiWrapper.getFileNames("files")[0];
            Enumeration fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getParameterNames();
            String param = request.getParameter("files");
        }
            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and im using fileUpload interceptor:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
<interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
```

this is the request:

> ```xml
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryjBpjIWpSdq4RzL0X
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"
>
> C:\fakepath\SMSMassploadOladDate.xls
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryjBpjIWpSdq4RzL0X
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="serviceIdMass"
>
> 647
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryjBpjIWpSdq4RzL0X
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contentTypeMass"
>
> 1
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryjBpjIWpSdq4RzL0X
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename=""
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
> ```

Shouldn't file content type be "`application/ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel`"
instead of `application/octet-stream`? and filename shouldn't be empty?

I really cant get what is the wrong with files?

Comment: WHAT is the problem exactly ? The request doesn't start ? I guess the problem is in your javascript, maybe because you're reading the fake field instead of the read input file's value. Try with `var hasNotUploadFile=   $('#uploadBtn').val();`

Comment: the problem is i cant get the file its not being sent to the server side, when  request files value is null.
 i have updated the script to check whether the user has uploaded a  file or not.

Comment: First of all, try removing completely the script, and sending the file normally. Does it work ?

Comment: I think it will be better use Struts2 FAQ http://struts.apache.org/docs/how-do-we-upload-files.html

Comment: i have commented the hidden parameters too, but it still the same the file is null.
im using bootstrap.

Comment: Did you add Struts File Upload Dependencies commons-fileupload and commons-io?

Comment: yes i did add commons-fileupload and commons-io.

Comment: i have solve the issue, in struts.xml i was just extends struts-default",it should be extends "struts-default,json-default".

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue, in struts.xml i was just extends "struts-default",it should be extends "struts-default,json-default".
also its related to blueimp plugin, i tried to use, "main.js" library was invoked and make my code not work.